# Expressing appreciation to a third party in an email

Tags: expression-choice

I am replying an email to my project supervisor who has arranged a co-marker for my project. I am replying to the supervisor alone but I would like to express in the email my appreciation to the co-marker as well.

In my mother tongue I would say something like 'Please tell her my gratitude for becoming the co-marker of my project'. This is just to show my gratitude for the third party not involved in the email communication, but I am not expecting the supervisor really to laboriously tell the co-marker. Is there a nicer or perhaps more formal way of expressing this?

If there is a better way to express my appreciation in English please suggest it as well :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: A relatively informal way but still polite thing would be something like "Please thank X from me for her help" or "Please say thank you to X from me". You could be a lot more formal and polite, depending on your familiarity with who you're writing to, and I'm not sure exactly of your situation or what would be appropriate there. You don't normally say "tell someone your gratitude" in English: you might say "tell them you are grateful" or "tell them thank you".

Comment: @StuartF 'tell them I am grateful' sounds exactly right! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more formal way would be something like "I would also like to 'relay' or 'extend' my gratitude to "X" for their input and support with the project.